# Customize Mediawiki's monobook.css with some skins

Tags: ubuntu, mediawiki, css

I have installed MediaWiKi on Ubuntu server. I am trying to customize the wiki's appearance, so I  tried different skins (fratman, GuMax, and mozillawiki)  None of them satisfied me.  I want a skin that looks like this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSkin).  It has smooth tabs and sidebar but does not lose the wiki specific appearance.

Does anybody know if it's possible to customize the wiki to look like the one in the link?

Comment: Please don't migrate to `Stackoverflow` where I already posted and deleted as I didn't get any response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skin used for Wikipedia, Vector, is the [default skin for MediaWiki version 1.17 and above](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFAQ#How_can_I_use_Wikipedia.27s_new_skin_.28Vector.29_on_my_wiki.3F). By editing the CSS files that make up the skin you can change it to look how you want, given enough CSS skills.

Comment: Isn't it possible editing the `common.css` file with mediawiki 1.15

Comment: It is, but it's easier to start with something that looks almost like what you want.